# Необходим парсер для видеофайла при перемещении на ListView.Используем библиотеку MediaInfo

Tags: c#, wpf, парсер, listview

Информация о файлах должна добавляться из MediaInfo (пользователь может перетаскивать файлы в карточку программы и все данные должны собираться автоматически).

Далее информация записывается в пять полей ListView.Вопрос кто работал с MediaInfo, можете показать несколько примеров работы с ней в wpf проекте.

```
    <Window x:Class="ProCards.View.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ProCards.View" xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:ProCards.ViewModel" 
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            Title="Картотека передач" Height="450" Width="800" Background="Aquamarine" WindowState="Normal" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" ResizeMode="NoResize">
        <Grid >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TabControl Grid.Row="0" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTabItem}" TabIndex="0">
                <TabItem Name="CardsTab">
                    <TabItem.Header>
                        <TextBlock Text="Карточки программ"/>
                    </TabItem.Header>
                    <TabItem.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu>
                            <MenuItem Header="Редактировать" Command="{Binding OpenEditItemWnd}"/>
                            <MenuItem Header="Удалить" Command="{Binding DeleteItem}" />
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </TabItem.ContextMenu>
                    <ListView x:Name="ViewAllCards" ItemsSource="{Binding AllCards, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCard}" AllowDrop="True" Drop="ViewAllCards_Drop" DragEnter="ViewAllCards_DragEnter" >
                        <ListView.View>
                            <GridView x:Name="cardGV">
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Название карточки" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=NameProgram}"/>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Год выпуска" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=YearOfIssue}"/>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Описание" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Description}"/>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Имена актеров" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ActorsNames}"/>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Список видео файлов" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ViewAllCards_Drop}"/>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Кол-во видео фaйлов" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=PositionVideoFiles.Count}"/>
                            </GridView>
                        </ListView.View>
                    </ListView>
                </TabItem>
                <TabItem Name="VideoInfoTab">
                    <TabItem.Header>
                        <TextBlock Text="Информация по видеофайлам"/>
                    </TabItem.Header>
                    <ListView x:Name="ViewAllVideos" ItemsSource="{Binding AllVideoFiles}">
                        <ListView.View>
                            <GridView>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Имя файла" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=FileName}"/>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Хронометраж" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Timing}"/>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Путь к файлу" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Path}"/>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Формат кадра" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=FrameFormat}"/>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Размер файла" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=FileSize}"/>
                            </GridView>
                        </ListView.View>
                    </ListView>
                </TabItem>
            </TabControl>
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <Button Content="Новая карточка" Command="{Binding OpenAddNewCardWnd}"/>
                
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ProCards.Model
{
    public class Video
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public string Timing { get; set; }
        public string Path { get; set; }
        public string FrameFormat { get; set; }
        public string FileSize { get; set; }
        public int CardId { get; set; }
        public virtual Card Cards { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public Video VideoFilePosition
        {
            get
            {
                return DataCard.GetVideoFilesById(CardId);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Необходим пример кода c# для работы с библиотекой MediaInfo(методы по извлечению полей метаданных файла). Парсинг видеофайла методом dragdrop и его привязка к моему проекту XAML разметке.

Comment: Явно вопрос делится на два: работа с драг-энд-дрор и вытаскивание метаданных, когда путь к файлу уже известен

Comment: Согласен,но нам уже известна переменная filePath.Дальше не понятно куда двигаться

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Включаем драг-дроп на ListView:

```
<ListView x:Name="ViewAllVideos" ItemsSource="{Binding AllVideoFiles}" DragDrop.Drop="ViewAllVideos_Drop" AllowDrop="True">
```

В обработчике дропа пишем:

```
private void ViewAllVideos_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (string path in (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop))
    {
        mediaInfo.Open(path);

        mediaInfo.Option("Inform", "General;%FileSize/String3%");
        string fileSize = mediaInfo.Inform();

        mediaInfo.Option("Inform", "General;%Duration/String2%");
        string timing = mediaInfo.Inform();

        mediaInfo.Option("Inform", "Video;%Width% x %Height%");
        string frameFormat = mediaInfo.Inform();

        AllVideoFiles.Add(new Info
        {
            FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path),
            Timing = timing,
            Path = path,
            FrameFormat = frameFormat,
            FileSize = fileSize
        });
    }
}
```

Параметр `DataFormats.FileDrop` позволяет получить данные о перетаскиваемых из Проводника файлах.

Далее с помощью MediaInfo извлекаем желаемую информацию.

Comment: Большое спасибо!!!

Comment: Интересно как связать Id обоих listview,чтобы при добавлении файла подсвечивалась строка с актуальной инфой левого ListView(ViewAllCards)

Comment: @Дмитрий - не спрашивайте в комментариях. Создавайте новую тему с вопросом.